# How do I pass different values depending on the imported data in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I want to take data from js files classified as categories such as 'Delivery' and 'Cafe' and deliver different data to different pages.

I thought about how to import it using map(), but I keep getting errors such as 'products' is not defined.'

It must be done, but it is not implemented well with javascript and react weak. If you know how to do it, I'd appreciate it if you could let me know.

**Products.js**

```
export const Product = [
  {
    Delivery: [
      {
        id: '101',
        productName: '허니랩',
        summary: '밀랍으로 만든 친환경 식품포장랩 허니랩.',
        description:
          '~~',
        images: ['3k7sH9F'],
        companyName: '허니랩',
        contact: '02-6082-2720',
        email: 'lesslabs@naver.com',
        url: 'https://honeywrap.co.kr/',
      },
      {
        id: '102',
        productName: '허니포켓',
        summary: '밀랍으로 만든 친환경 식품포장랩 허니랩. 주머니형태.',
        description:
          "~~",
        images: ['4zJEqwN'],
        companyName: '허니랩',
        contact: "02-6082-2720",
        email: "lesslabs@naver.com",
        url: "https://honeywrap.co.kr/",
      },
],
},
{
    HouseholdGoods: [
      {
        id: '201',
        productName: '순둥이',
        summary: '아기용 친환경 순한 물티슈',
        description:
          '~',
        images: ['4QXJJaz'],
        companyName: '수오미',
        contact: '080-000-3706',
        email: 'help@sumomi.co.kr',
        url: 'https://www.suomi.co.kr/main/index.php',
      },
      {
        id: '202',
        category: ['HouseholdGoods'],
        productName: '순둥이 데일리',
        summary: '친환경 순한 물티슈',
        description: '품질은 그대로이나 가격을 낮춘 경제적인 생활 물티슈',
        images: ['OMplkd2'],
        companyName: '수오미',
        contact: '080-000-3706',
        email: 'help@sumomi.co.kr',
        url: 'https://www.suomi.co.kr/main/index.php',
      },
],
},
];
```

**Delivery.js**
(The file was named temporarily because I did not know how to classify and deliver data without creating a js file separately.)

```
import React from "react";

function Delivery(
  productName,
  companyName,
  contact,
  email,
  url,
  summary,
  description
) {
  return (
    <div className="Product">
      <div className="Product__data">
        <h3 className="Product__name">{productName}</h3>
        <h4>{companyName}</h4>
        <h5>Contact: {contact}</h5>
        <h5>Email: {email}</h5>
        <h5>URL: {url}</h5>
        <p className="Product__summary">{summary}</p>
        <p className="Proudct__descriptions">{description}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Delivery;
```

**Category.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Delivery from "./Delivery";
import { Product } from "./Products";

class Category extends React.Component {
  render() {
    state = {
      products: [],
    };
    this.setState(_renderProduct());

    return <div>{products ? this._renderProduct() : "nothing"}</div>;
  }

  _renderProduct = () => {
    const { products } = this.state;
    const renderProducts = products.map((product, id) => {
      return (
        <Delivery
          productName={Product.productName}
          companyName={Product.companyName}
          contact={Product.contact}
          email={Product.email}
          url={Product.url}
          summary={Product.summary}
          description={Product.description}
        />
      );
    });
  };
}

export default Category;
```

Sorry and thank you for the long question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few different problems I've found.

First is that you call `setState` inside render in the `Category` component, this causes an infinite loop. Instead call `setState` inside a lifecycle method like `componentDidMount` or use the `useEffect` hook if using functional components.

Another problem is that `state` in `Category` is also defined inside `render`. In class components you would normally put this in a class constructor outside of render.

In your `setState` call you refer to `_renderProduct()`, this should be `this._renderProduct()` instead.

Now the main problem here is the structure of your data / how you render this structure.

`Products` is an array of objects where each object either has a `Delivery` or `HouseholdGoods` property which is an array of products. I would advise you to change this structure to something more like this:

```
export const Product = {
  Delivery: [
    {
      id: "101",
    },
    {
      id: "102",
    },
  ],
  HouseholdGoods: [
    {
      id: "201",
    },
    {
      id: "202",
    },
  ],
};
```

or this:

```
export const Product = [
  { id: "101", productType: "Delivery" },
  { id: "102", productType: "Delivery" },
  { id: "201", productType: "HouseholdGoods" },
  { id: "202", productType: "HouseholdGoods" },
];
```

I personally prefer the second structure, but I've implemented the first as this seems to be what you were going for:

```
class Category extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ products: Product });
  }

  render() {
    const { products } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {products
          ? Object.keys(products).map((productKey) => {
              return (
                <div key={productKey}>
                  {products[productKey].map((product) => {
                    return (
                      <Delivery
                        key={product.id}
                        productName={product.productName}
                        companyName={product.companyName}
                        contact={product.contact}
                        email={product.email}
                        url={product.url}
                        summary={product.summary}
                        description={product.description}
                      />
                    );
                  })}
                </div>
              );
            })
          : "no products"}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

We need a nested loop here, because we need to map over each property key and over the array of objects inside each property. If you use the other structure for `Product` I've shown, you can simply map over `Product` without needing two loops.

Now the last important problem was that you weren't destructuring the props inside your `Delivery` component, instead you should do something like this:

```
function Delivery({
  productName,
  companyName,
  contact,
  email,
  url,
  summary,
  description,
}) {
  return (
    <div className="Product">
      <div className="Product__data">
        <h3 className="Product__name">{productName}</h3>
        <h4>{companyName}</h4>
        <h5>Contact: {contact}</h5>
        <h5>Email: {email}</h5>
        <h5>URL: {url}</h5>
        <p className="Product__summary">{summary}</p>
        <p className="Proudct__descriptions">{description}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Example Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-euclid-wj0sl?file=/src/Delivery.js:28-545)